# Should I be concerned about using off-the-shelf inductors in high-voltage switching applications?

Tags: voltage, switch-mode-power-supply, inductor, insulation

I'm interested in building a SEPIC converter with an input range of up to 1200 VDC. Digikey lists a large number of inductors, which may be viable for my application. But I'm concerned about the voltage in question, and none of the inductors I've looked at have a voltage rating. Are there any particular concerns for using an off-the-shelf inductor in a switching converter at this voltage? Insulation breakdown? Winding style? Something I haven't thought of?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is yes.  Your list of concerns is good (insulation breakdown, winding approach) and I would add to it the clearance between the terminations/leads of the inductor, including any exposed wire between the winding and the component lead that is soldered to the PCB.  This is probably not a huge factor, since the L you choose will be pretty big and the leads will probably be spaced far apart, but depending on the winding style, you might wind up (ha!) with the terminals next to each other which could allow for leakage paths or arcing.

[This article](https://www.coilcraft.com/getmedia/393e18e1-adbc-45b6-bbe7-5923255e72fc/doc712_inductor_voltage_ratings.pdf) from Coilcraft explains some of the reasons why voltages aren't specified for inductors and echoes the concerns you've already raised for a high voltage application.

Answer (score 1):

- If you really mentioned [SEPIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-ended_primary-inductor_converter), you need to specify an input level range (Vin,min ; Vin,max) instead of a single level, and also specify an output level laying within that range Vin,min < Vout < Vin,max. If your Vout < Vin,min < Vin,max or Vout > Vin,max > Vin,min, you don't need SEPIC at all. Also, speaking about power conversion, you did not specify the output current you need, i guess the current is more than 10 A.
- Input rated 1200 Vdc is something from HVDC (U >= 1 kV) techniques, IMO while SEPIC is something from LVDC (U << 1kV). Therefore, maybe the thing that you need is not SPEIC, but something like **solid state** [power] **transformer** (SST, also called electronic transformer) or single phase power inverter with ballast? That devices are typically built around specialized IGBT modules + controllers and if you need to find other related components (capacitors, inductors, etc...) you need to select IGBT+ctrl first and be guided by its datasheets and/or application notes.
- In the end, if still SEPIC is exactly the architecture you want, you can search a power transformer with rated 1) power, 2) voltage, 3) insulation, 4) inductance, and 5) frequency satisfying your design, because a) in many SEPIC instances at least two power inductors may be winded at a single core, and b) to find out a rightly specified power transformer is a less complicated task than to do the same for an inductor. Also, when you'll find the appropriate transformer, you'll find the answers on the questions about the inductor you need, examining the transformer's construction.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you can find any inductor with a voltage rating. The only way for the voltage on an inductor to become an issue is if it is located too close to another component, such as a shield, where it might arc to. Otherwise, Q, self resonant frequency, and max current are the major concerns.

Remember that the voltage between individual windings, or across the leads, is typically tiny.

Comment: Well, the voltage across the leads will be my full input voltage, at least during the on-state of the switching cycle.

Comment: OK.  So essentially, you are asking if the insulation between every turn could break down and short out. Yes?

Comment: That, or any other possible problems I haven't thought of.

Comment: This is not true; high voltage coils are guaranteed to not break down, not absorb water etc.

Comment: I did not know this, but in hind sight, it makes sense.