# Is it theoretically possible to be killed with coin cell batteries?

Tags: batteries

Other than the obvious eating them, is it possible to squeeze enough electricity out of a coin cell battery to cause harm? Maybe using a boost converter with a large capacitor? Or maybe using a bunch of them in series?

Comment: With one cell: probably yes but the chance of actually killing someone with only the energy from one coin cell is quite low I think. The famous electric chair uses more power but still most victims aren't killed instantly. Coin cells are not good at delivering a large amount of energy in a short time. Which is what would be needed. Not seeing the point of this question though.

Comment: Related: youtu.be/8hwLHdBTQ7s

Comment: They can be fatal if swallowed.

Comment: @pjc50 The OP already called that out in the first clause.

Comment: Drop them from a huge building onto someone?

Comment: @PlasmaHH considering them to be the same as coins, [it won't even hurt much](https://www.theguardian.com/cities/2014/mar/20/urban-myths-skyscraper-coin-kill-you)

Comment: @ChrisH Propulse them with a coilgun then !

Comment: You can also make a [stack](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8hwLHdBTQ7s).

Comment: See references I've added to Jonk's answer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A CR2032 holds about 2400 useful Joules of energy. Operating entirely within specification, it can supply \$200\:\mu\textrm{A}\$.

---

If applied subcutaneously, \$10\:\mu\textrm{A}\$ can be sufficient to cause fibrillation. So if you could apply the battery directly near the heart and underneath the skin, I suppose it could directly kill someone without any additional circuitry.

From an editorial in ***Anesthesia & Analgesia***, June 2010, Volume 110, Number 6, International Anesthesia Research Society, pp 1517-1518, "Electrical Safety in the Operating Room: Dry Versus Wet," by Steven J. Barker, PhD, MD, and D. John Doyle, MD, PhD, FRCPC, the following quote is found:

> Microshock refers to very small currents (as little as
>   \$10–50\:\mu\textrm{A}\$) and applies only to the electrically
>   susceptible patient, such as an individual who has an internal conduit
>   that is in direct contact with the heart. This conduit can be a pacing
>   wire or a saline-filled central venous or pulmonary artery catheter.
>   In the electrically susceptible patient, even minute amounts of
>   current (\$10\:\mu\textrm{A}\$) may cause ventricular fibrillation.

(The above information was pointed out in a comment here by Russell McMahon and is a substantial improvement over citing a Wiki page.)

---

I've [read](http://www.stephstuff.com/esafe/StoredEnergy.htm) that death can be caused with as little as 50 Joules. But I think 100 Joules is a more certain estimate. Lethality (with AC, anyway) is pretty common even at \$200\:\textrm{V}\$. So if I had to make an educated guess, I'd probably guess that using a Sanyo OS-CON Aluminum-Polymer (way too expensive and you'd need lots of them) or aluminum capacitor (such as [Vishay BCcomponents' Aluminum Electrolytics](http://www.vishay.com/docs/28432/299phl4tsi.pdf)), with \$200\:\textrm{V}\$ and 100 Joules would be sufficient. This suggests a value of \$5\:\textrm{mF}\$.

However, it would take a while to achieve. Assume you can design a circuit that is, overall, 50% efficient in charging this capacitor from a single CR2032 while staying fully within specs and drawing just \$200\:\mu\textrm{A}\$ from it. Then on first blush it would take 10000 seconds or about \$2\:\frac{3}{4}\$ hours to charge it up for one such use if you could sustain \$200\:\mu\textrm{A}\$ throughout the process. But the CR2032 is only capable of sustaining about \$600\: \frac{\mu\textrm{J}}{\textrm{s}}\$ of power. So really, I think this would take closer to four days to achieve. (And that doesn't account for capacitor leakage. With the Vishay capacitor mentioned above, leakage power may be below charging power near the end, but it probably will add a fair bit more time to the process.)

---

So the answer is probably "technically, yes" but rather unlikely as it would be quite odd to open someone up in order to stick a button battery across some tissues inside their body near the heart (read: very low probability) and it is similarly unusual to find a circuit designed to charge up a large, low ESR capacitor from a battery supplying just \$600\:\mu\textrm{W}\$ continuous and requiring almost a week to charge up (read: low probability.)

Of course, now that someone is thinking this way, I am sure such a circuit will be promptly designed and then sold as pet rocks to millions of happy consumers, making this a significant problem in the wild. ;)

Comment: I believe OP means something like get a high-voltage oil-filled industrial capacitor, and make a voltage multiplier out of the coin, and charge it to 10kV. But these caps can kill you even without any coin if left unattended without crowbar short.

Comment: @AliChen Hmm. I'd read it as wondering about a boost circuit for any sufficiently high voltage. Not necessarily 10 kV.

Comment: Also, coin cells are routinely used in cheap magnifiers with LEDs, so it is not unheard of having ~10mA from a CR2032 coin. So it should charge a 10uF cap to 3kV in about 1 hour.

Comment: Nice explanations. By the way, [here is](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/266419/generating-high-voltage-100v-from-5v-usb-supply/267285#267285) the circuit to charge a high-voltage capacitor from a lower voltage. It needs to be adjusted to draw less current,  because as it is, it is designed to draw power from USB. But the idea is the same. You can start selling.

Comment: @AliChen Yes, I knew that up to 10 mA has been drawn from them using those LED lights. I have LOTS of them here, in fact. I was very careful in my wording to stay within given specs so that the total lifetime Joule rating would remain without equivocation, though.

Comment: @dim Hmm. :) It's a start, I suppose. The big cap will cost some money though. I hadn't added capacitor leakage to the puzzle,  so the whole idea will require careful attention to details (and not just the few I mentioned.)

Comment: If you open someone's chest and put a lump of metal in the heart, it really doesn't need to be a battery ;)

Comment: @Mołot +1 just for making me laugh :D

Comment: FWIW re " ...  it would be quite odd to open someone up in order to stick a button battery across some tissues inside their body near the heart ..." -> In some surgical and patient care situations you have the potential (pun noted) for a low resistance path from heart to exterior to exist.  One well know cardiac surgeon has written a number of papers and gives lectures re the dangers when such paths exist and the low levels of current and voltage able to potentially (pun noted again) cause death.

Comment: eg "Electrical Safety in the Operating Room: Dry Versus Wet
Steven J. Barker, PhD, MD,* and D. John Doyle, MD, PhD, FRCPC† , www.anesthesia-analgesia.org pp1517-1518 June 2010 • Volume 110 • Number 6

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Thanks for the addition, which provides good authority for what was nothing more than a guess I'd made. If you don't mind, I'll include it into the answer itself.

Comment: Jonk -  I am happy for you to include it. For future reference - all material here is CCbySA or better so cross copying is always allowed. I usually say "as xxx said ..." but I think duplication of external technical fact without citation of SE source is potentially permissible, although a hat-tip usually helps ensure nobody is upset. In my case, I'm happy for people to utilise material from my comments without attribution if that seems most appropriate, as long as factuality is maintained.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Oh, I intended to mention you as the source. I can't think of a reason not to, anyway. Just a few words of typing and only good coming from it. I'm just not sure if having comments is sufficient. But when I read an answer, I sometimes don't read as much of the comments as perhaps I should. Projecting my behavior onto others is why I think including it in the answer helps.

Comment: We agree: I agree that adding information from useful comments useful to an answer is a good idea. It improves the answer, makes the information more accessible and removes the risk of information being lost (as long as the system does not delete your answer :-) ). |  Re " ... I can't think of a reason not to,  ..." -> you are welcome to mention my name BUT 'I didn't do anything' :-) ie I did not do any of the work in preparing the information (of course) and cannot vouch for it's value or even degree of relevance (although in this case I think its OK in both respects to a reasonable extent).

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I took the time to download the article and read it, to get the fuller context. It's a short editorial and doesn't delve into the science. States a few things, but it is more directed at some kind of internal _argument_ going on amongst doctors, I think. It has a kind of _defensive_ summary at the end. (And yes, you _located_ the article and even if it is an editorial that obliquely mentions currents to worry over, it's better than a Wiki page. I had missed it. So thanks, anyway!)

Comment: This is less useful than the title may suggest "Operating Rooms as Wet/Dry Locations Risk Assessment Project" http://www.nfpa.org/~/media/files/news-and-research/resources/research-foundation/rfsurgicalwetdrylocations.pdf?la=en

Comment: But this 2012 discussion document provides some insight as to where they went from there and why. At a brief skim it sounds like the argument AGAINST GFI equipment is that power interuption that has wider impacts may cause more harm than good in a theatre environment. http://www.hfmmagazine.com/articles/237-current-compliance

Comment: "microshock" is a better search term. Your coincell battery is back in play, alas.  Limits 10 uA. Ventriculat fibrillation 20-100 uiA !!! | 
[... http://www.ccanesthesiareview.com/qf/electrical_shock.pdf ... ](http://www.ccanesthesiareview.com/qf/electrical_shock.pdf) and fwiw 10uA = 20 uA. | And/but [Wikipedia - Microshock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microshock) - nb - they say there has NEVER been a documented occurrence - useful reading.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon You are over-educating me! And yes, that's a nice, quick-to-read PDF that narrows in on the question and answers it in a way anyone can understand. Thanks.

Comment: Over-educating me is a major problem. :-). ALMOST everything is interesting. There are too many [**pebbles and pretty shells on the seashore, and the great ocean calls ever slightly louder**](http://www.lib.cam.ac.uk/exhibitions/Footprints_of_the_Lion/introduction.html) .

Answer (score 0):

The simple answers are:
1) **Very unlikely** to be killed or greatly harmed, with **only one** cell.
2) **Very certain** to be killed or greatly harmed, with **enough** of them!

Answer (score 0):

A long sharp steel wire in a wood handle, shoved between ribs into heart, it might work much better if using *two* sharpened wires, with coin-cell attached between!

PS

2400 joules in an energy-storage oil capacitor at about 3KV will explode flesh like a bomb.  (That's the quarter-shrinker capacitor used in room-freshener mode, where it explodes a single cherry into fine mist.  Very, very loud.  Smells nice.)  Hydrostatic shock reflecting around within the body may tear up blood vessels and brain tissue.  http://amasci.com/amateur/capexpt.html