# how to charge 320 v capacitor with 9v battery

Tags: voltage, capacitor, boost

How can I charge a **320-volt 110-uF capacitor** with a **9-volt battery**? 
I'm a begginer at electronics. So, Kindly guide me.
Thankyou.

Update: I found this schematic on how a camera capacitor is charged and discharged.
[image: Oscillator and capacitor]

Is this how i should do it?

Comment: if you state the purpose of charging the capacitor, it will help to help. do you want to charge the cap to 320 V, really?

Comment: Piece of advice: beginner in electronics and 320 V doesn't match. If you're not sure what you do, don't do it.

Comment: @Umar im trying to make a high voltage generator with a spark gap to produce a emp.

Comment: @Umar im trying to make a high voltage generator with a spark gap to produce an EMP.
I got the capacitor from a camera flash, I know I could have used the camera circuit, but I tried charging up the capacitors it only charged up to 9 volts.

Comment: You can do a web search for "photoflash capacitor charger" but note the warning: "Danger high voltage - operation by high voltage trained personnel only." And yes, if you connect a 9V battery directly to a capacitor, it will charge to 9 volts.

Comment: @olltsu im careful with the voltages, I just want to charge it up and produce a spark gap with a switch. Im sure of what im doing, just need to know, how to charge it up. i wont be blowing up any components.

Comment: @KenShirriff Thankyou, i will keep it safe, thanks for your concern.

Comment: See http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/266419/generating-high-voltage-100v-from-5v-usb-supply/267285#267285, with a few adjustments. But if you don't get how it works, don't do it.

Comment: I dont understand it quite well, so i think i shouldnt be doing it.

Comment: Two people trying to ask how to build a taser in one week? Didn't the flux capacitor idea work on the last one.

Comment: @RoyC Actually im building a EMP device which requires a spark gap, indirectly a taser too.

Comment: If you were studying anything to do with EMP you would know how to do this without our help.

Comment: i really dont know, so im asking if you can guide me, on how i can charge the capacitor to its full potential just like the camera circuit does and then discharge it just like the camera does. but here instead of a flash i want to create a spark gap.

Comment: Is this a very complicated thing? if yes then i think i should just buy a high voltage converter from ebay. Because ive been trying to find out on the whole internet. I got ideas of how voltage is stepped up, but im not sure if thats the right way i should charge my high voltage capacitor.

Comment: In the days when disposable cardboard film cameras (with flash) were available, this was a very easy project. If you can still find one, all the electronics you need are there.

Comment: Thankyou Bryan, I think I still have a old disposable camera lying around somewhere at my grandmothers place, I'll start searching.

Answer (score 0):

An ideal capacitor will instantly charge up to whatever voltage you connect it to.A practical capacitor will take some time to charge up owing to a finite internal resistance (referred to as equivalent series resistance or ESR),but eventually, it will still reach the source voltage.A practical capacitor also has a maximum voltage rating till which it'll operate safely,in your case, that is what the 320V means.It does not mean that the capacitor will charge up to 320V irrespective of your source voltage.If you provide 9V,it'll charge up to 9V,if you give 440V,it'll most likely explode.Another aspect you should be aware of w.r.t practical capacitors is that apart from max voltage,there is a limit to the max current they can handle,this parameter is often difficult to find in datasheets though.

So to answer your question,in order to charge up your capacitor,just connect it to the 9V battery (well below 320V so no problem there) in series with a current limiting resistor of value say R, and wait till approx 5 x R x C seconds (C=110uF in your case).After that if you connect a voltmeter across the cap, you should see 9V across it but not 320V.To understand capacitor charge time calculation better,refer to this: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/capchg.html

In the example below,I've used a 1k resistor which will limit the max current to 9/1000 = 9mA and make the 99% charge time to approx 550ms

Safety tip: Your capacitor specification makes it most likely an electrolytic type,they have a polarity and **does not like reverse voltages**.Please ensure you connect the positive and negative terminals of the cap with the respective polarities of the source or there might be a risk of explosion!

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbBIez.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this won't get the capacitor to its full potential, would it? And we have to also use a diode so that the capacitor doesn't start charging the battery with a higher voltage.

Comment: 5 x R x C seconds, is 5 a contant in this?

Comment: Imagine the capacitor as a big bucket.If you have only one glass of water (source of smaller voltage),you can not possibly fill up the bucket to the brim (max voltage rating of the capacitor).In your context,to charge the cap to 320V (not recommended anyway since you should always maintain a margin from max rating), you need a source of 320V.There are techniques for generating 320V from 9V though,but that is another topic altogether

Comment: Yes, 5RC is the approximate time it takes for a capacitor to charge up to about 99% of the source voltage.Refer the RC Charging Circuit Curves in this webpage for details: http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/rc/rc_1.html

Comment: Actually thats my question, how do i charge it up to 320v with a 9 volt battery.

Comment: @sbp9674 Boosting the voltage to a few hundred volts before charging the cap is obviously what OP wanted, and the main purpose of the question. Although I agree the question wasn't properly formulated.

Comment: This site explains how its done with a 1.5 volt battery
http://electronics.howstuffworks.com/camera-flash3.htm

Comment: @dim how can i edit the question so that i get a proper answer?? cause i havent yet. Thankyou for letting me know.

Comment: "How can I charge a 110µF capacitor **to** 320 volts, **from** a 9-volt battery?" is much less ambiguous. But In my opinion, your question is the same as the one I mentioned as a duplicate (for which there are answers). The problem is, if you don't understand the answers there, it means you don't have the skills to build this. Find another project, maybe.

Comment: @dim seems so.Since OP claimed to be a beginner,I assumed question was oriented more towards RC fundamentals as opposed to boost conversion which is clearly a more advanced topic

Comment: Can you suggest few topics which I should study for this? I'm gonna use a bug swatter for now to create the emp. I just wanted to use the capacitor from my old digicam, but seems quite advanced for me now.

Comment: @dim I'll see the other similar topic and learn. Thankyou for sharing the topic.